# Найдите среднее арифметическое суммы заказов вида delivery для каждой валюты. Результат отсортируйте в лексикографическом порядке по валюте

Tags: java

```
Помогите решить задачу в одну строчку))без ручного ввода валюты. Мой вариант:
```

```java
import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
enum Type {DELIVERY, PICKUP}
class OrderData {
  final Type type;
  final String currency;
  final Long amount;

  OrderData (@NotNull Type type,
  @NotNull String currency,
  @NotNull Long amount) {
    this.type = type;
    this.currency = currency;
    this.amount = amount;
  }

  String getCurrency() {
    return currency;
  }

  Long getAmount() {
    return amount;
  }

  Type getType() {
    return type;
  }
}

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    OrderData orderData1=new OrderData(Type.DELIVERY, "EUR", 2000L);
    OrderData orderData2=new OrderData(Type.DELIVERY, "USD", 15L);
    OrderData orderData3=new OrderData(Type.DELIVERY, "RUB", 200L);
    OrderData orderData4=new OrderData(Type.PICKUP, "RUB", 1250L);
    OrderData orderData5=new OrderData(Type.DELIVERY, "USD", 35L);
    OrderData orderData6=new OrderData(Type.PICKUP, "USD", 55L);
    OrderData orderData7=new OrderData(Type.DELIVERY, "RUB", 100L);
    List<OrderData> orderlist =new ArrayList<>();
    orderlist.add(orderData1);
    orderlist.add(orderData2);
    orderlist.add(orderData3);
    orderlist.add(orderData4);
    orderlist.add(orderData5);
    orderlist.add(orderData6);
    orderlist.add(orderData7);
    System.out.println( getAverageDeliveryMapByCurrency(orderlist));
  }

  public static Map<String, Double> getAverageDeliveryMapByCurrency(List<OrderData> orderData) {
    Map<String, Double> map=new HashMap<>();

    map.put("EUR",orderData.stream().filter(t->t.getType()==Type.DELIVERY).filter(t->t.getCurrency()=="EUR").mapToDouble(t->t.amount).average().getAsDouble());
    map.put("USD",orderData.stream().filter(t->t.getType()==Type.DELIVERY).filter(t->t.getCurrency()=="USD").mapToDouble(t->t.amount).average().getAsDouble());
    map.put("RUB",orderData.stream().filter(t->t.getType()==Type.DELIVERY).filter(t->t.getCurrency()=="RUB").mapToDouble(t->t.amount).average().getAsDouble());
    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: ну группируйте по валюте в какой нибудь TreeSet, значением считайте среднее или что вам надо.

Comment: Предложили такой вариант:        Map<String, Double> collect = list.stream().filter(t -> t.getType() == Type.DELIVERY)
                .collect(groupingBy(OrderData::getCurrency, averagingLong(OrderData::getAmount)));

Answer (score 0):

- С использованием `Collectors.averagingLong`

```java
public static Map<String, Double> getAverageDeliveryMapByCurrency(List<OrderData> orderData) {
    return orderData
        .stream() // Stream<OrderData>
        .filter(od -> Type.DELIVERY == od.getType())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            OrderData::getCurrency,
            Collectors.averagingLong(OrderData::getAmount)
        ));
}
```

- С использованием `Collectors.collectingAndThen`:

```java
public static Map<String, Double> getAverageDeliveryMapByCurrency(List<OrderData> orderData) {
    return orderData
        .stream() // Stream<OrderData>
        .filter(od -> Type.DELIVERY == od.getType())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            OrderData::getCurrency,
            LinkedHashMap::new, // для сохранения порядка
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toList(), // List<OrderData>
                list -> list.stream()
                    .mapToDouble(OrderData::getAmount)
                    .average()
                    .getAsDouble()
            )
        ));
}
```

Тест:

```java
List<OrderData> orderlist = Arrays.asList(
    new OrderData(Type.DELIVERY, "EUR", 2000L),
    new OrderData(Type.DELIVERY, "USD", 15L),
    new OrderData(Type.DELIVERY, "RUB", 200L),
    new OrderData(Type.PICKUP, "RUB", 1250L),
    new OrderData(Type.DELIVERY, "USD", 35L),
    new OrderData(Type.PICKUP, "USD", 55L),
    new OrderData(Type.DELIVERY, "RUB", 100L)
);
System.out.println( getAverageDeliveryMapByCurrency(orderlist));
// -> {EUR=2000.0, USD=25.0, RUB=150.0}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробный разбор!!!

Comment: @СалаватМигранов, если ответ был полезен, можете отметить его, поставив зелёную галочку слева от ответа, и/или проголосовав за него